# problems using pcl_visualizer

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to use pcl_visualizer, but it cannot detect vtkCommand.h file. Actually, I can find this file in /usr/include/vtk-5.8 manually. I am using Ubuntu 12.4 and Fuerte.

Thank you very much!

```
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_pcl: 2.3 sec ]                                                                                                       [ 1 Active 27/28 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package my_pcl
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  -- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build
  cd build && make -l8
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_pcl.dir/src/ttt.o
  In file included from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h:49:0,
                   from /home/nutan/new/my_pcl/src/ttt.cpp:5:
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/visualization/common/common.h:39:24: fatal error: vtkCommand.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_pcl.dir/src/ttt.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_pcl.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nutan/new/my_pcl/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package my_pcl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/nutan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120626-164634/my_pcl/build_output.log                
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< my_pcl [FAIL] [ 2.34 seconds ]                                                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package my_pcl. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Built 28 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] /home/nutan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120626-164634
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37281/problems-using-pcl_visualizer/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I missed your question and posted my own--Sorry I am new to ROS

I found the answer --[PCL Visualizer error](http://answers.ros.org/question/39444/pcl-visualizer-error/?answer=39744#post-id-39744)

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2